# Selecting all columns in sqLite table and storing it in a (mutable) array - and return array to caller

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, sqlite, tableview

I have searched for a solution for several days now and unfortunately could not find any relevant information which suits the needs of my app.

**What I'm trying to do is:**
call an sqLite query method
method queries sqLite table (selects all columns)
saves selected rows and columns in an array
array must return to caller
UITableView must show the returned values

My code:

FirstViewController.m:

```
result = [queryObject myQueryMethod]; //result is of type NSMutableArray
```

Query.m:

```
NSString *myUsername;  
NSString *from;  
NSString *to;  
NSString *message;  

querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to = '%@'" , myUsername];  
query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];  

NSMutableArray *allMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_userDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) {  

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {  
            from = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];  
            to = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];  
            message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];  
            [allMessages addObject:message];  //MY PROBLEM..
        }

        return allMessages; //return to caller in FirstViewController.m

    }
```

**My problem is:** how can I add all columns (three) to an array, and return the array to caller inside FirstViewController.m in order to sort through the indexes for UITableView?
To display info in the tableview, I use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I would appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the value of all 3 columns, you should use dictionary.

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
 {  
      from = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];  
      to = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];  
      message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];  

      NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: from, @"From", to, @"To", message, @"Message", nil];
      [allMessages addObject:dict];  //MY PROBLEM..
}
```

Now while getting the value, fetch it from dictionary:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"To"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding the message value to the array.  You should create an object with properties for each of the three columns and return an array of those objects instead.

Alternatively you can add the three strings to the array and retrieve each value based on its location:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 3];
NSString *to = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 3 + 1];
NSString *message = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row * 3 + 2];
```

Of course, you need to add the other values to the array:

```
[allMessages addObject:from];  //MY PROBLEM..
[allMessages addObject:to];
[allMessages addObject:message];
```